# NullPointerException while setting ArrayAdapter in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

In this `FragmentActivity` , I am having a `NavigationDrawer` using a `ViewPager` as the "main content" for the "drawerlayout" and a `ListView` for the "drawer".

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` in the line where adapter is being set ...

```
public class VPM extends FragmentActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ListView listView;
private String[] menu;
private ViewPager mPager;
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vpm);


    // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new   ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);


    menu= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menuitems);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.navDrawer);
    **listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<> (getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu));**

   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(VPM.this, menu[position] + "was selected",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   });


   }
 }
```

Logcat -

```
05-03 00:20:54.331  26585-26585/com.example.sairav.app3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sairav.app3/com.example.sairav.app3.VPM}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5283)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sairav.app3.VPM.onCreate(VPM.java:58)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)**
```

Comment: Best thing to do is see which of the variables is null. If, for example, it is listView, then that means findViewById(R.id.drawerList) failed, possibly because the layout doesn't contain drawerList.

Comment: Can you put your layout file as well?

Comment: yeah , i used wrong listview id while instantiating as in xml file . problem solved. thanks